# Trouble with 'keydown' Event in Chrome Extension: Capturing Backspace Action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, keydown, text-manipulation

I am creating a Chrome extension (code [here](https://github.com/stcksmsh/EmojiType/)) and am having trouble with the "keydown" event. I want to use it to capture a 'backspace' before it happens, in order to switch the text the user is typing before it is deleted. However, with the current way I am doing things, which involves creating a function `keyDown(event){...}` and adding `document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown)`, when the function is called, the `event.srcElement.innerText` contains the text after the deletion takes place. To clarify, if an editable element contains 'abcd' and I press backspace, I will get the text 'abc' from the event handler, rather than 'abcd'.

P.S. If you view my code and notice any other issues with it, please do let me know. I am not a seasoned developer and would appreciate any input.

Comment: Use **window**.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, **true**) to run it in the first phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @wOxxOm for the answer.
I just needed to change `document.addEventListener('keydown', function)` to `window.addEventListener('keydown', function, true)` and the function launched before the text was deleted by a backspace.